# Как реализовать аудио читалку под Android?

Tags: android

Стало интересно, как реализована технология по превращению текста в аудио например в тех же переводчиках от гугла, Яндекса и тд. Информацию как-то не особо удалось найти. Интересует именно реализация под Android. Может кто знает?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech